# Is there any way I can add more than 10 locations to Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Is there any way to add more than 10 locations to Google maps (by becoming a premium user or other paid services)? Or is a default for all users ?

Answer (score 7):

You may simply concatenate destinations in the URL.
For instance my original 10 destinations may be like this...

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Bridgewater+Pet+Boarding,+7596+Austin+Rd,+Saline,+MI+48176/Saline,+MI/Milan,+MI/Britton,+MI/Tecumseh,+MI/Decker+%26+Sons+Insurance+Inc,+265+S+Main+St,+Onsted,+MI+49265/Jackson,+MI/Chelsea,+MI/Stockbridge,+MI/Pinckney,+MI/@42.2695261,-84.0432186,10z/am=t/data=!3m1!4b1!4m63!4m62!1m5!1m1!1s0x883cb93059245a13:0xb18965ef7d27ed2e!2m2!1d-83.876656!2d42.160273!1m5!1m1!1s0x883cbacfff5b8a61:0xb76c9793c1fef3cd!2m2!1d-83.7816075!2d42.1667072!1m5!1m1!1s0x883ca1b0a6c765c1:0xc0b6d49db60eabe5!2m2!1d-83.6824384!2d42.0853204!1m5!1m1!1s0x883c914c71b582a7:0x666f59bb1d0657bb!2m2!1d-83.8310513!2d41.9867114!1m5!1m1!1s0x883c94c6800b5fd5:0x990fd176e2cc9ed7!2m2!1d-83.9449417!2d42.0039331!1m5!1m1!1s0x883ce3f9a3dbd17f:0x3ecb62ea861aa8ff!2m2!1d-84.189328!2d42.00273!1m5!1m1!1s0x883d25593e337b6b:0xce45a6328e9bd551!2m2!1d-84.4013462!2d42.245869!1m5!1m1!1s0x883ccd94fe56d5e9:0x4cdc35f9fb05974f!2m2!1d-84.0205029!2d42.3180919!1m5!1m1!1s0x88232be2d26b506f:0x6da0248900121f!2m2!1d-84.1805146!2d42.4511466!1m5!1m1!1s0x882335ec2d941ba5:0xa2c75a3cfb4e03b1!2m2!1d-83.9463358!2d42.4567013!2m1!6e4

By going into the URL, and manually adding more destinations (here, I just added a comma, + State abbrev / City name  like this )

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Bridgewater+Pet+Boarding,+7596+Austin+Rd,+Saline,+MI+48176/Saline,+MI/Milan,+MI/Britton,+MI/Tecumseh,+MI/Decker+%26+Sons+Insurance+Inc,+265+S+Main+St,+Onsted,+MI+49265/Jackson,+MI/Chelsea,+MI/Stockbridge,+MI/Pinckney**,+MI/Dexter,+MI/Ypsilanti,+MI/Monroe,+MI/Adrian,+MI/Hillsdale,+MI/Albion,+MI/Marshall,+MI/Charlotte**,+MI/@42.2699797,-84.0432186,9z/am=t/data=!4m110!4m109!1m5!1m1!1s0x883cb93059245a13:0xb18965ef7d27ed2e!2m2!1d-83.876656!2d42.160273!1m5!1m1!1s0x883cbacfff5b8a61:0xb76c9793c1fef3cd!2m2!1d-83.7816075!2d42.1667072!1m5!1m1!1s0x883ca1b0a6c765c1:0xc0b6d49db60eabe5!2m2!1d-83.6824384!2d42.0853204!1m5!1m1!1s0x883c914c71b582a7:0x666f59bb1d0657bb!2m2!1d-83.8310513!2d41.9867114!1m5!1m1!1s0x883c94c6800b5fd5:0x990fd176e2cc9ed7!2m2!1d-83.9449417!2d42.0039331!1m5!1m1!1s0x883ce3f9a3dbd17f:0x3ecb62ea861aa8ff!2m2!1d-84.189328!2d42.00273!1m5!1m1!1s0x883d25593e337b6b:0xce45a6328e9bd551!2m2!1d-84.4013462!2d42.245869!1m5!1m1!1s0x883ccd94fe56d5e9:0x4cdc35f9fb05974f!2m2!1d-84.0205029!2d42.3180919!1m5!1m1!1s0x88232be2d26b506f:0x6da0248900121f!2m2!1d-84.1805146!2d42.4511466!1m5!1m1!1s0x882335ec2d941ba5:0xa2c75a3cfb4e03b1!2m2!1d-83.9463358!2d42.4567013!1m5!1m1!1s0x883cb4461addaadd:0x7720b2384ae38d6b!2m2!1d-83.8885552!2d42.3383697!1m5!1m1!1s0x883ca86dd9b8faad:0xf9c6f7405f4a3451!2m2!1d-83.6129939!2d42.2411499!1m5!1m1!1s0x883b6fa6b2cc2bcd:0x1aff3b8ff9f0d231!2m2!1d-83.3977101!2d41.9164343!1m5!1m1!1s0x883cf1979399bb57:0xd146d433cdecd56c!2m2!1d-84.0371659!2d41.8975471!1m5!1m1!1s0x883d72e59fdc700b:0x7b2bb9a774645d37!2m2!1d-84.6305101!2d41.9200472!1m5!1m1!1s0x883d451b39295621:0xdfbec60a4a2a6007!2m2!1d-84.7530304!2d42.243097!1m5!1m1!1s0x8817e2977eec1989:0x47494b2e9d9f5659!2m2!1d-84.9633148!2d42.2722641!1m5!1m1!1s0x8822af0b087b30f9:0x13b42ed69ae241f1!2m2!1d-84.8358211!2d42.5636478!3e0

I was able to add quite a few more destinations...
Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the best option, and also shows that the 10 destination limit is not there for any overwhelming technical issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the "better" version of Google Maps. It is possible to switch to [the old version](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3045828?hl=en). Follow the link provided or search for

> Switch back to the classic version of Maps

You can also try an alternative solution such as:

- [OSRM](http://map.project-osrm.org/)
- [Open MapQuest](http://open.mapquest.com/)
- [Your Navigator](http://www.yournavigation.org/), or
- [Bing Maps](http://www.bing.com/maps).

Comment: As of... some time recently... you can apparently no longer switch back to classic.  If you try, it puts you into some kind of special "lite" mode which has even fewer features.

Answer (score 1):

Ten destination points is currently the maximum for multiple-destination driving directions. There is no premium option and currently no way to get around this limit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible but only in the old Google maps.

Comment: In order for this answer to be more useful, could you clarify how you can access the old Google maps?